# VB.Net Trying to download file, just get file contents

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, vb.net-2010, download

So my issue is this, I have the following code:

```
  <HttpGet>
    Function downloadExtract(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal formatId As String)
        Dim path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/app_data/extracts/" + id.ToString + ".csv"

        Dim file = New FileInfo(path)

        If (file.Exists) Then
            Response.ClearHeaders()
            Response.ClearContent()

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", file.Name))

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString)

            Response.ContentType = "application/x-download"

            Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName)

            Response.End()
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If

    End Function
```

Now as far as I can tell this should be finding the file, and then if it exists sets some response headers and chucks the file across.

Now this exact same code elsewhere in the project does the above flawlessly and lets me download said file, however I have an issue now where it just seems to do absolutely nothing.

Checking the dev console on my browsers I can see that my Ajax request to the controller handling this returns 200 and all is well, the only difference I can see between the succesful request and the one that sits there doing nothing is that the succesful one says it cannot show me the response data whereas the one that sits there twiddling it's thumbs shows me that the response data was the files contents as text and I have no clue why it is doing this.

I've been tearing my hair out on this for the best part of the day now any help would be greatly appreciated!

Since posting I've noticed a couple more differences in the dev console,

The one that work says type: document and  initiator: Other

The one that doesn't says type: xhr and initiator: jquery-1.9.1.js:8526

The code in the JS files that calls the relevant functions are:

Working:

```
self.getExtract = function (outputId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location + "/DownloadExtract",
            data: {id: outputId}
        });
};
```

Not working:

```
self.downloadFile = function (id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location + "/downloadExtract",
        data: {id: self.extractId, formatId: self.format}
    });
};
```

And in case it makes any difference the links in the vbhtml files are:

Working:

```
<td><a href="/ListExtracts/DownloadExtract?id={{extract.id}}">Download</a></td>
```

Not Working:

```
<a target="_self" href="" ng-click="runExtract.downloadFile()"><i class="icon-download"> Download Extract</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right well due to being an idiot I hadn't noticed that the above was actually going straight to the controller from the hyper link rather than shooting it off in Javascript.

Changing the  to:

```
<a target="_self" href="/RunExtract/downloadExtract?id={{runExtract.extractId}}&formatId={{runExtract.format}}"><i class="icon-download"> Download Extract</i></a>
```

Did the trick!

....... yes I feel silly now!